# Get the closest date of a specific week day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, date, time

I have a date and I want to find the closest Thursday for instance. Though I want it to work for any week day, not just Thursday.

To avoid confusion, I don't want the next Thursday, I want either the previous or next Thursday, whichever is the closest. So it has to be bidirectional.

I have written a code that does it but I'm clearly not happy with the while loop and I was wondering if you guys had an idea of a better implementation.

```ruby
def closest_date(date, wday)

  # already ok
  return date if date.wday == wday

  before_date = date
  after_date = date

  until before_date.wday == wday && after_date.wday == wday
    before_date -= 1.day unless before_date.wday == wday
    after_date += 1.day unless after_date.wday == wday
  end

  if (date - before_date).to_i > (after_date - date).to_i
    return after_date
  else
    return before_date
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```
def closest_day(weekday_name,date=Date.today)
  distance = Date.parse(weekday_name).cwday - date.cwday
  (date + (distance.abs < 4 ? distance : 7 - distance.abs).days)
end
```

Where `weekday_name` is, for example, "`thursday`".

Comment: Damn I tried something like that but must have gotten an error somewhere. Many thanks!

Comment: instead of '  (date + (distance.abs < 4 ? distance : 7 - distance.abs).days)
' which fixes the sign of the distance, you can use (distance + 7) % 7 ==> distance is now [0..7]! 
HTH

Comment: def closest_day(cwday, date = Date.today)
    distance = cwday - date.cwday
    (date + (distance.abs < 5 ? distance : 7 - distance.abs).days)
  end

Answer (score 1):

```
def closest_date(date, wday)
  distance = wday - date.wday
  date + distance.days
end
```

Comment: date = Saturday, wday = 0
closest_date should be "date + 1.day", you're returning "date + -6.day"