# Closest day of week to specific date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm trying to calculate National Sovereignty Day of Argentina which is celebrated on the Monday closest to 20 November.

I tried to find PHP solutions here but just found a Ruby solution: [Get the closest date of a specific week day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328441/get-the-closest-date-of-a-specific-week-day)

How can I implement this for PHP?

Comment: Did you start coding anything in PHP? If so show us

Comment: @RiggsFolly, nope, I didn't as I cannot figure out what kind of logic to apply here.

Comment: It's trivial to do that with Remind https://dianne.skoll.ca/projects/remind/

Comment: _“the Monday closest to 20 November”_ - so that would be the previous Monday if the 20th was anything up to and including Thursday, and the next one if it was Friday or “later” in the week. (When we assume the week starts on Monday, which PHP’s `N` date format character gives.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$date->format("N")` you will get a numeric representation of the weekday (1-7 for Monday-Sunday). If its greater than 4, which is greater than Thursday, select the next Monday. If not, it's the previous Monday.

If `$date->format("N") === 1`, it's the date provided, and we don't need any modifications.

```
$date = new DateTime("November 20th");
$dayOfWeek = $date->format("N");
if ($dayOfWeek > 1) {
    $date->modify($dayOfWeek > 4 ? 'next monday' : 'previous monday');
}
echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
```

- [Live demo](https://3v4l.org/t0mR8)

Comment: It doesn't work for 2020 as it returns 2020-11-16 instead of the correct closest Monday on 2020-11-23. However the logic is fine (it should be > 4 I believe), so I'll accept this approach! Thank you!

Comment: Seems you're correct! I'll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Could try something like this:

```
<?php

function getSovDay($year)
{
    $date = new \DateTime($year."-11-20");
    $weekDay = $date->format("N");
    if ($weekDay == 1)
    {
        return $date;
    } elseif ($weekDay <= 4) {
        return $date->modify("previous monday");
    } else {
        return $date->modify("next monday");
    }
}

for($i = 2000; $i <= 2200; $i++)
{
    echo getSovDay($i)->format("Y-m-d")."\n";
}
```

Comment: What if `$date->format("N") == 1`, what happens then?